# recursive chmod on current directory

Tags: chmod

I was in a directory I wanted to recursively chmod all of its contents (make writable by the group).

I did (with sudo):  `chmod -R g+w .`

And something weird happened (I lost all permission to the directory I was in, until I fixed that)

I ended up with this (i.e. *read* permission has been unset!):

`d-wx-wx--x   5 _www  _www    160B 24 Jan 11:14 storage/`

After apparently recovering from something the above command did which I do not understand, I then did equivalent of `cd ..`
followed by `chmod -R g+w storage`, this time from the parent directory, address the directory I want to target in that normal manner.
That gave me what I wanted (as far as I can make out, but I'm still a bit disoriented by this).

Are these two commands not equivalent?

Comment: Try with a `-v` flag (verbose) to see what's going on

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use `chmod -R g+w *` and not `chmod -R g+w .` Not really clear why though.

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `*` means different files, I think it gets a little strange with files that start with a dot though